# how to get country location on Google Map in iphone using Country name only?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

In my iphone application i have integrated Google Map.I want to show the country location on Google map using only country Name Only.(Not needed to use its latitude and longitude).The input only will be the country name?(i.e India) to the google Map and Map will locate it with indicate pinpoint.

Is it possible to locate the country using the country name in google Map?

Is any body has any solutuion or code snippet or any useful link,which would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Mishal Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no geocoder in the iPhone SDK at this time. You'll have to use a library likes http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/iphone-api/Geocoding_iPhone_example or call Google geocoder API, Yahoo etc.